# TYPO3 default locallang.xlf when the website's base language is not English

Tags: localization, typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I have a website which has as base language the Greek language. So on my fluid i have a `<f:translate key="more_button" />` viewhelper.

Since the locallang.xlf has to be always in English and i can not add a file with the name en.locallang.xlf, i have no idea how to turn into Greek.

I tried to override it with TypoScript but i failed.

I tried something like that:

```
plugin.tx_akmyBasebase._LOCAL_LANG.gr.more_button = Value
plugin.tx_ak_myBase_base._LOCAL_LANG.gr.more_button = Value
```

Though on my TOB my plugin does not show, since i havent included any static template, so i do not know how valid is the idea.

The next thing i tried is that: **locallang.xlf**

**1.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <xliff version="1.0">
  <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2017-07-18T14:10:33Z" product-name="bw_apoKardias_base">
    <header/>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="more_button" xml:space="preserve">
           <source>More</source>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

and the i created a file **gr.locallang.xlf**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xliff version="1.0">
   <file source-language="en" target-language="gr" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2017-07-18T14:10:33Z" product-name="bw_apoKardias_base">
    <header/>
    <body>
        <trans-unit id="more_button" xml:space="preserve">
            <source>More</source>
            <target>Value</target>
        </trans-unit>
    </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

I hoped that TYPO3 somehow will understand (TypoScript Configuration) which language is my base language and it would automatically read the **gr.locallang** but it doesn't work.

**My TypoScript:**

```
config {
  uniqueLinkVars = 1
  linkVars = L(int)
  sys_language_uid = 0
  sys_language_mode = content_fallback;2,1,0
  sys_language_overlay = 0
  language = gr
  locale_all = gr_GR.utf8
  htmlTag_langKey = el
  htmlTag_dir = ltr
  htmlTag_setParams = lang="el" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
}
```

**AND**

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
  config {
     sys_language_uid = 1
     language = en
     locale_all = en_EN.UTF-8
     htmlTag_setParams = lang="en" dir="ltr" class="no-js"
    }
[global]
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

After the answer from @Morgus Lethe , my problem was actually the `.`. Apparently this `.` is necessary in order get the multi language function to work. Go figure.

I wouldn't find the solution to my problem if it wasnt for @Bernd Wilke πφ as well who pointed out that my language prefix was wrong. So thank you both for your help.

Best regards,

Comment: You use a plugin, the template in question is a fluid template from the plugin. how can you find your templates, if you have no (active) typoscript settings?

Comment: <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:ak_myBase_base/Configuration/TypoScript/Setup.typoscript">
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:EXT:ak_myBase_base/Configuration/TypoScript/Constants.typoscript">

Comment: I have edited my question so you can see my TypoScript configuration too

Comment: I just noticed the special langcode for greek. Maybe this is the reason for your problems? are you sure about the `gr` in the filename `gr.locallang.xlf`? I have not found any locale named `gr_GR.utf8` but `el_GR.utf8`

Comment: `locallang.xlf` does not need to be in english. It is the default language and it will fall back to this if there are no other translation found. Over typoscript you set `config.language = xy`, then it takes xy.locallang.xlf if found, but fall back to normal locallang.xlf if not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only know for sure for Typo3 v9.5, which has great multilanguage functionality, but I have a very similiar situation:
My default language is Slovenian, the url is http://example.com
And English is defined as an extra site language in the Site configuration, then added to my site through the List module. The url is http://example.com/en/

In order to translate a label (for example) I have my locallang.xlf file, that contains something like this:

```
  <trans-unit id="common.contact" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Contact</source>
  </trans-unit>
```

And then I have my sl.locallang.xlf file (for Slovenian), which contains something like this:

```
  <trans-unit id="common.contact" xml:space="preserve">
    <source>Contact</source>
    <target>Kontakt</target>
  </trans-unit>
```

I can then use this in my fluid template, to translate the label:

```
<p>
<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:common.contact" />
</p>
```

Typo3 then automatically detects which language it should display and uses the appropriate translation.

Be careful, I think you have to use the `.` character to define the label, and also make sure that you have the correct language tag, locale and iso code in the language configuration.

Comment: There is no neccessity to use '.' dots in labels. In contrary it was(!) a big problem when trying to redefine the value with typoscript as typoscript splits array levels at dots and so no label with dots was found. A special treatment needed to be invented in TYPO3 4.2(?) to handle language labels with dots.

Answer (score 2):

You need a proper language configuration, so TYPO3 knows what language is your current.

Before TYPO3 9 (what version do you use?) it was some typocript like this:

```
// no sys_language record: uid=0
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE.UTF-8
config.htmlTag_langKey = de

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
// sys_langugage record with uid=1, does not need to match the L value!
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_US.UTF-8
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]
```

since TYPO3 9 the language configuration is done in the site configuration:

```
rootPageId: 2
base: 'https://www.beispiel.de/'
languages:
  -
    languageId: '0'
    title: Deutsch
    navigationTitle: ''
    base: /
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    hreflang: de-DE
    direction: ltr
    typo3Language: de
    flag: de
  -
    languageId: '1'
    title: English
    navigationTitle: ''
    # base: 'https://www.example.com/' 
    base: /en/
    locale: en_US.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    hreflang: en-US
    direction: ltr
    typo3Language: default
    flag: us
    fallbackType: strickt
:
```

From the URL TYPO3 can detect the current language: with TS condition on URL parameter L (TYPO3 <9), or domain or path segment (since TYPO3 9) and use the correct translations file.

Comment: It is TYPO3 8.7. And yes i have the TypoScript configuration like you wrote.

Comment: are you sure your `locallang.xlf` is read for english? I get the impression the 'translation' comes from another language file, where no greek translation exists.

Comment: my homepage looks like that: https:// myhomepage .org/ . This is the Greek one. For English looks like that: https:// myhomepage. org/en/ . Since the Greek language is the default, the gr variable doesnt show on the url. Only the extra languages

Comment: if you change the text in your 'locallang.xlf': do you get that changed text where you have `<f:translate key="more_button" />` in your fluid template?